# MySQLi PDO - incremeting integers gives incorrect result when starting at 0

Tags: php, pdo

I have a MySQLi table with a field `views` with type `int(11)` and default value `0`. When updating using the following statement there is an incorrect value. However this happens only when the initial value is `0` and after update it is changed to `2`. Then `2` is updated to `3` which is correct.

What is happening here?

```php
$statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE table SET views = views + 1 WHERE id=?");
$statement->execute([$id]);
```

This is a simple scheme:

```
| views |                   | views |                   | views |
---------  -> update +1 ->  ---------  -> update +1 ->  ---------
|   0   |     ERROR HERE    |   2   |                   |   3   |
```

Comment: one quick solution. First get particular record and save it's "view" value in variable. Increment with 1 and then update the query with new "view" value. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don’t see any logical explanation here, other than you are probably unknowingly executing the same statement twice.